# Develop game like Angry Birds in flash

Tags: flash, flashdevelop

Am trying to have an estimate time and cost of developing a flash game like Angry Birds game and publish it in facebook.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can downlowd this software http://www.adobe.com/it/products/flash.html it's a little bit expensive but worth every penny.

Another way is html5 and javascript...